# Configure Different Web.config for local and AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, web-config, umbraco, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am playing around **AWS** to set up a **Elastic Beanstalk** where i would run a .Net (Umbraco CMS) app. The problem I am facing is that, the app has secrets and connectionStrings on Web.config. Also, right now, that config is added to repo which is pushed to codeCommit, and if everything works, i want to set up the pipeline to deploy my push to the beanstalk.

So, I want to know the best way of creating separate files, so that when I push my local changes, i dont overwrite the web.config on aws.

**Some solution I thought of, but I dont know how i can execute them:**

1) Set up Environment variable and somehow transform web.config values with that.

2) Create separate file in server (don't know how), and ignore the local web.config. I dont know if thats a good solution.

3) Create some build process to transform the web.config.

May be there is a better way. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is via an S3 bucket that is locked down. [Here is an example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html#rds-external-credentials) from the Elastic Beanstalk docs. You'll create an .ebextensions config file to tell EB to retrieve your secrets on deploy.

Example:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: "s3"
          buckets: ["my-secret-bucket-123456789012"]
          roleName: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"

files:
  "/tmp/beanstalk-database.json" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-secret-bucket-123456789012/beanstalk-database.json
```

There are guides for a number of languages describing how to build the DB connection in EB, [including .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.rds.html#dotnet-rds-connect).